# What's the best way to find where a paper is mentioned in a paper that cites it?

Tags: publications

Sometimes when I read a research paper I want to read what later researchers said about it because I find their summaries helpful. So I look on Google Scholar at who cited the paper and take a look at those papers. What's the fastest way to find where the original paper is mentioned? My current approach is to search by the last name of the author until I find the citation number down at the bottom. Then I search for that citation number. This doesn't seem like a good approach and is especially bad when the citation number is a single digit. What's a better way? Is there some software that can help me with this?

Comment: The answer depends a lot on the citation format. In my field, it's rather typical to use reference indexes (e.g. [5]), so I search for that.

Comment: A similar question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395516/237687

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think that link or your answer addresses the question here. Given a paper A that cites paper B, the OP is asking for a quick way to find the locations where B is referred to in the text of A.

Comment: @GoodDeeds so reading is not an effective solution - really.

Comment: Why not write a script (vba or similar) to do what you want?

Comment: What kind of speed-up are you expecting? Your current approach seems reasonable. You could get around the single digit problem by searching for "[7" or ",7", it still isn't perfect, because [1-9] won't be found.

Comment: @SolarMike Many academics don't code.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim and many do... But I had the misfortune of providing an excel based answer on here before so I am not rushing to repeat that experience - some appreciate with downvotes...

Comment: @SolarMike How do you use VBA on a PDF or webpage anyway?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I know how to get text from a pdf then after that search for patterns, what do you do?

Comment: @SolarMike I don't know VBA. Author-date citations are the norm in my field, so this isn't a huge problem for me, Ctrl+F works fine.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim so if you do the same thing repeatedly code it...

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry, didn't mean to get into an involved conversation. Just offering an answer to your posed question of "why not write a script." Sometimes AcSE seems to forget not everyone is in math/CSE or even in the sciences.

Comment: You can make this easy for people who read your papers, by using the latex package [backref](https://ctan.org/pkg/backref?lang=en); see [this helpful latex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54541/precise-back-reference-target-with-hyperref-and-backref).  The end result is hyperlinks from the bibliography to where each paper is referenced in the text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[scite](https://scite.ai) does a great job at that.
Additionally, It's able to show you where in the paper to find such statements.

"...uses deep learning to classify citation statements in three categories: those that provide disputing or supporting evidence, and others, which mention the cited study without providing evidence for its validity."